# Wordpress -- permalink with custom post types

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type as seen below,

```
function transactions_register() {

$args = array(

    'label' => __('Transactions'),

    'singular_label' => __('Transaction'),

    'public' => true,

    'show_ui' => true,

    'capability_type' => 'post',

    'hierarchical' => false,

    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "transaction"),

    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')

);



register_post_type( 'transaction' , $args );
```

}

I have set my permalinks to be like this `/%category/%postname` however when I navigate to a transaction, the URL looks like this,

> http://www.domian.com/transaction/test

However this returns the following server error

> The page cannot be found

How can I make it so my custom post type will work with my permalink setting?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add custom post type, just go to Settings -> Permalinks and click on "Save" or was it "Update". It does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create custom post type or custom taxonomy you have to goto Settings -> Permalinks and hit save. its wordpress known bug.