# Custom Post Types and Template Hierarchy

Tags: wordpress

On the following dev site, I set up a custom post type for "Articles".  The post type name is "zu_articles" and the slug is "articles".  Everything is working in the Dashboard and I'm able to generate a listing of articles.  But when you click the article link, it goes to a 404.  I have the following page created: single-zu_articles.php based on my understanding of the WP template hierarchy. I also have single-aricles.php if it is based on the slug and that doesn't work either.

http://zimmernutrition.com.s137737.gridserver.com/

There is a "Latest Article" widget under the content slider on the right to see everything.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Brett

Comment: I don't think that 404 error is caused by missing template file. WP will try to find emplate file for your custom post type, and if it's missing, it will use single.php. I think you should look at sql query generated by WP_Query class, it will give you an idea about what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  What file am I looking in?

Comment: Open wp-includes/query.php and find a line that says $this->request = " SELECT $found_rows $distinct $fields FROM $wpdb->posts $join WHERE 1=1 $where $groupby $orderby $limits"; , then add var_dump($this->request); after this line.

Comment: I don't think this did anything for me.  I still get the 404 error page.  What should I be looking for?  Do I need to change something on the single-zu_articles.php page?

Comment: This wasn't meant to fix 404 error, but it would help us to identify the problem. What was the output of var_dump($this->request); ?

Comment: I never get an error or any code output, it goes right to the 404 page.

Comment: Can you try die($this->request) instead of var_dump($this->request)?

Comment: That kills the entire site, nothing loads but an error for any page.

Comment: What message does it display?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /nfs/c09/h03/mnt/137737/domains/zimmernutrition.com/html/wp-includes/query.php on line 2641

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're not going to believe this...did some more hunting on StackOverflow and found this post:

[Wordpress -- permalink with custom post types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486560/wordpress-permalink-with-custom-post-types)

All I had to do was resave my f'n existing permalinks in the Dashboard.

Thanks for staying with me.  With I understood why this had to be done and why it fixed it.